# Storage Account Queries for Read/Write Operations and Data Retrieval

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I need to price up a storage account using the azure calculator, I need to run queries on an existing storage account to get the following data :

```
Write Operations
Read operations
Iterative read operations
Iterative write operations
Data Retrieval
Data write
```

Does anyone know what the best way is to get the above attributes for an existing storage account

Answer (score 0):

Configuring diagnostic setting to send logs to Log Analytics. Then, for each type of transaction (For example: “Write” transaction), you need to catalog all the operations that map to a write operation. They can use this article to do that - [Map each REST operation to a price - Azure Blob Storage | Microsoft Learn.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/map-rest-apis-transaction-categories)

You can use a log analytics query to get a count of transactions for each category. For example, this query gets a count of all write transactions:

```
StorageBlobLogs
| where OperationName == "PutBlob" or
  OperationName == "PutBlock" or
  OperationName == "PutBlockList" or
  OperationName == "AppendBlock" or
  OperationName == "SnapshotBlob" or
  OperationName == "CopyBlob" or
  OperationName == "SetBlobTier"
| summarize WriteSize = sum(RequestBodySize), WriteCount = count())

Or .. for specific containers with this:

StorageBlobLogs
| where OperationName == "PutBlob" or
  OperationName == "PutBlock" or
  OperationName == "PutBlockList" or
  OperationName == "AppendBlock" or
  OperationName == "SnapshotBlob" or
  OperationName == "CopyBlob" or
  OperationName == "SetBlobTier"
| extend ContainerName = split(parse_url(Uri).Path, "/")[1]
| summarize WriteSize = sum(RequestBodySize), WriteCount = count() by tostring(ContainerName)
```

We feature these examples in this article here - [Best practices for monitoring Azure Blob Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-storage-monitoring-scenarios)

As for “Data Write”, it’s showing as “Free” in the pricing page, so I’m not sure how that factors into the calculation. “Data Retrieval” is done on a per GB bases for select tiers.

Also, the “StorageBlobLogs” table is blob service specific. For activity with other services, you’d query a different table.